# Finding every checkbox control on an xaml page

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, windows-phone

I'm trying to programatically find all checkboxes so I can see if they were checked. The code below is what the xaml looks like and there is a checkbox created for every item in the list. Does anyone know how I can do this in my code?

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="3" Height="350" Name="scrollViewer" >
                <ItemsControl Name="lstTop10Picks">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="6" Name="gridTop11Stocks">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
                                    <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
                                    </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                                </CheckBox>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Symbol}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Market}" />
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Return}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>

var stocks = doc.Element(ns + "ArrayOfStockRating").Elements(ns + "StockRating")
        .Select(n => new
        {
            Id = count += 1,
            Symbol = n.Element(ns + "Symbol").Value,
            Market = n.Element(ns + "Market").Value,
            Return = n.Element(ns + "ShortRating").Value
        })
        .ToList();
```

lstTop10Picks.ItemsSource = stocks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to add property in your model to store it's state (checked/unchecked) :

```
public class MyModel
{
    .....
    .....
    public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Then bind your `CheckBox` to the above mentioned property :

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
    Style="{StaticResource CheckStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
    <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
    </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
</CheckBox>
```

That way you don't have to get your code messy trying to find all `CheckBox` from XAML, instead you can easily iterate through your model and check it's `IsChecked` property (or even better using LINQ).

**UPDATE :**

Turned out that you're using anonymous type here, so we don't need class definition or partial class. Simply change your LINQ `Select()` part to provide `IsChecked` property with default value set to `false`, for example :

```
.Select(n => new
        {
            Id = count += 1,
            Symbol = n.Element(ns + "Symbol").Value,
            Market = n.Element(ns + "Market").Value,
            Return = n.Element(ns + "ShortRating").Value,
            IsChecked = (bool?)false
        })
```

Then you can iterate through your model later like so :

```
foreach(dynamic n in (IList)lstTop10Picks.ItemsSource)
{
    bool? isChecked = n.IsChecked;
    //do something with isChecked
}
```

Comment: The reason why I'm not doing that is because my code loads data from a database for the user to see and then the user checks on which items they want to save. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. I understand the two way binding but how would I create a partial class to extend my model. I am guessing it is bound so when a user checks it, you somehow see the rest of the data from that class? I will update with the method I'm using to load the data from

Comment: check my update section. And my small mistake fixed : `IsChecked` should've been `bool` instead of `int`.

Comment: I just have two questions or I suppose clarifications. First should I use two way binding so the anonymous class gets updated when it is checked because I thought that regular binding was one way only. Also when I submit the info and I'm checking what items were checked, how am I supposed to open the class again. I have never done it this way before

Comment: 1. Each property has different default binding mode, for example `TextBox.Text` default binding is two-way without we need to explicitly set `Mode=TwoWay`. I'm strongly suspect `IsChecked` has `TwoWay` as default binding mode (not 100% sure tho)

Comment: Foreach won't work on the itemssource because it is an object and doesn't have a get enumerator. Is there another way of doing that?

Comment: Actually, I already checked MSDN before posting my answer and [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is `IEnumerable` instead of `object`. Have you tried or that comment was just your guess?

Comment: The code looks correct and I have tried one way binding and two way binding but it isn't detecting any of the checkboxes being checked no matter how many I try. Do you have any idea what is causing this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56170/discussion-between-user3610374-and-har07).